# Comparing new and old session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

For an instance we have login page. We are creating session and append our text to it.. I am trying compare old session and new session. Lets put,

1) User login with test // if incorrect password , it will redirect back to login page and append "test" to session

2) But if User login with different username on the second try // i want to append it to a new session and compare it with old session . 
Lets say ,,

```
if(session1 is not equal to session 2){
   restart attempt incremental
} else if (session1 is to session 1){
  increment attempt to -1
}
```

Lets put it that 
our jsp file as follow

```
<form action="servlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

In our servlet file

```
doPost(HttpSe....){
//Get Parameter 
String name = request.getParameter("username");

//Create session
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("username", name);
String session_name = (String)session.getParameter("username");

//validate if username is = test, it will redirect

if(name.equal("test")){
  //this will redirect to different page
} else if(session_name.equals(name)){
  //do something..
} else {
 //do something...
}
```

I just need to compare old session and new session.

i tried using (session.isNew()) but it does not work, it will always redirect me to else statement ..

This is my actual code

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        HttpSession session_Newusername = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("Username", username);
        String session_Username = (String)session.getAttribute("Username");
        System.out.println(" data .... " + session_Username);

        int loginAttempt;
            if(session.getAttribute("loginCount") == null){
                session.setAttribute("loginCount", 0);
                loginAttempt = 0;
            } else if(session.isNew()) {
                System.out.println("If user key in same username");
                loginAttempt = (Integer)session.getAttribute("loginCount");
                if(loginAttempt  == 3){ 
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
                    session.setAttribute("message", "Your account is blocked, Please contact admin or wait for 2mins");
                    //System.out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
                    response.sendRedirect("Pages/Login/login.jsp");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("How many attempt left " + loginAttempt);
                    loginAttempt++;
                    int leftAttempt = 4 - loginAttempt;
                    session.setAttribute("message", "You are left with " + leftAttempt + " attempt");
                    //System.out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
                    response.sendRedirect("Pages/Login/login.jsp");
                }
                session.setAttribute("loginCount", loginAttempt);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("Pages/Login/login.jsp");
                System.out.println("username is not the same");
                session.invalidate();
            }

    }
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I want to store new value in a new session and compare it with the old value in the same session

Comment: Swap the values so you can easily store new value & compare it with other.

Comment: `request.getSession(true);` will only return a new session if one does not already exists - so both of your session variables are pointing to the same session

Answer (score 0):

When previous session is invalidated (closed after timeout for example) the Session attributes will be destroyed. So you cannot add those attribute and attempt to get it from previous already invalidated session. You can only access them within the same active session.

So, you cannot achieve what you want in that way. You need to store your data somewhere else for example in database or JVM memory. But not in session attributes.

If you want to determine in the same active session, then you need to check presence of `userName` attribute in the current session and then act as you want:

```
userName = (String) session.getAttribute("userName");
if (userName == null) {
    // here you don't have it from previous invocation of setAttribute
    session.setAttribute("userName", login);
} else {
    // you already setAttribute from previous invocation on current session
    // add you errors here
}
```